# gdb always fails with SEGV at the beginning of execution

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, virtualbox, macos-ventura

gdb fails with SEGV for each and every program I try to run. It obviously happens before entering main(), SEGV address is always something like 0x0000aaaa9aa5xxx9. It started after upgrade host system, Virtual Box and guest system, but I don't know which upgrade caused gdb to stop working.

Details:

```
#### Host macOS Ventura 13.01 ####
radoje@ramax ~ % uname -a
Darwin ramax.local 22.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.1.0: Sun Oct  9 20:14:54 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8792.41.9~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

#### Virtual box ####
ramax:~ root# VirtualBox --help
Oracle VM VirtualBox VM Selector v7.0.4

#### Guest system Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS ####
radoje@ubus:~$ uname -a
Linux ubus 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

radoje@ubus:~$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-xKiWfi/gcc-11-11.3.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

#### Trying to run basic 'hello world' program ####
radoje@ubus:~$ gdb /tmp/tmp.gzDY6CbzJm/cmake-build-debug/exp
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/tmp.gzDY6CbzJm/cmake-build-debug/exp

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000aaaa9aa5ac29 in ?? ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000aaaa9aa5ac29 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff7fe636c in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=<optimized out>, user_entry=<optimized out>,
    auxv=<optimized out>) at ./elf/rtld.c:1868
#2  0x00007ffff7fe285c in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=start_argptr@entry=0x7fffffffe470,
    dl_main=dl_main@entry=0x7ffff7fe4900 <dl_main>) at ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:256
#3  0x00007ffff7fe45b8 in _dl_start_final (arg=0x7fffffffe470) at ./elf/rtld.c:507
#4  _dl_start (arg=0x7fffffffe470) at ./elf/rtld.c:596
#5  0x00007ffff7fe32b8 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffffffe6e9 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Behaviour is almost identical for any program I try to run. Interestingly, fault address is always of pattern 0x0000aaaa9aa5xxx9.

Without gdb, programs run as expected.
Problem seems to be the same as this one:
[gdb always returns segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525002/gdb-always-returns-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Further findings: same guest setup running on previous MacOS Monterey and VirtualBox 6  works fine, which narrows potential bug to MacOS Ventura and/or VirtualBox 7.