# Error when using gdb, throwing SIGSEGV when there shouldn't be

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm having this simple c++ code:

```cpp
int main() {
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;
  int z = x + y;
  return 0;
}
```

Then I do `g++ -g main.cpp -o main`, then `gdb main` into gdb mode. Then I set break point by `b 2`, then `r`, then type `n`, immedately I get

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555513a in main () at main.cpp:4
4       int z = x + y;
```

I am very confused as this code is too simple and having nothing wrong.

Could somebody help? Thank you so much!

When I input `backtrace`, I got

```
#0  0x000055555555513a in main () at main.cpp:4
```

I don't know in which way it is incorrect.

If I set break point `b 4`, then `r`, then the program safely comes to line 4, but same thing happens if I use `n`. Very confused.

I'm running it in Debian virtual box but I don't think it's related.

Comment: Can you run the program without the debugger?

Comment: Works for me.  Do you have anything unusual in your environment, for example is `LD_PRELOAD` set?

Comment: Is this Virtualbox 7.0.4 on MacOS Ventura?.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes. Is this the root cause?

Comment: It looks like the reports [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992755/gdb-always-fails-with-segv-at-the-beginning-of-execution), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525002/gdb-always-returns-segmentation-fault), and [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=108016) have those two things in common. I haven't seen a solution yet.